# How to get a reference to SessionAuthenticationStrategy without configuring the strategy explicit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In a Spring Security 3.2 based application I have a explicit configured `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, that need an reference to the `sessionAuthenticationStrategy` (in order to invoke `.onAuthentication`).*

The `sessionAuthenticationStrategy` is the default one created by `<security:http>` (`HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser`).

My question: **Is how can I get an reference to the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` without configuring the complete `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` explicite, so that I can inject this reference in XML configuration?**

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
    access-decision-manager-ref="httpAccessDecisionManager">
    ...
    <security:custom-filter
             ref="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
             position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    ...
</security:http>

...

<bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    class=" o.s.scurity.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">

   <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="????">   <!-- ?? ->
   ...
</bean>
```

**my real `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is a customized subclass, but that should not matter for this question*

Comment: I opened an issue referencing this question.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3995

Answer (score 6):

I have had a look at the `HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser` (and the `HttpConfigurationBuilder.createSessionManagementFilters()`) that is the class responsible to parse the `security:http` tag and for creating of `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` bean.

Therefore I know that Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE create (in my configuration) a `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` bean and uses this as session strategy. This bean will get the default name: `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0`

So my current workaround is to have a reference to this bean, by its name:

```
<bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
     class=" o.s.scurity.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">

    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <ref
           bean="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0"/>                
    </property>
    ...
 </bean>
```

This workaround has some serious limitations:

- when a newer version of spring security works in an other way (creating an other bean) then it will fail.
- when there is an other `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` thats name is created with `ReaderContext.generateBeanName` then this approach may fail, because of `#0` maybe become `#1` (depends on the order in which the beans are created)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is no obvious way to get it.

But all the examples in Spring-Security reference manual are coherent on that : you should not even want to get it : all show an explicit `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` injected in the `UserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and if appropriate in the `SessionManagementFilter`.

According to the javadocs of these 2 classes, the default `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` are :

- `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` for Servlet < 3.1
- `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy` for Servlet 3.1+

So the correct way is to create a bean implementing `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` either one of the above defaults, or another implementation if you have special needs and use it wherever you need to.

Of course, it is always possible to use reflection to access private members of Spring security implementation classes, but you know it is *bad* and comes with high risk of getting broken on next release of Spring security.

Comment: How to select `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` impelementation based on servlet version used in servlet container?

Answer (score 3):

When working with JavaConfig (I'm afraid is not your case) you can get a reference by doing

```
        http.getConfigurer(SessionManagementConfigurer.class).init(http);
        http.getSharedObject(SessionAuthenticationStrategy.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [Ralph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26583562/710780), you can use a `FactoryBean` to get a reference to the `AuthenticationStrategy`.

```
public class SessionAuthenticationStrategyFactoryBean implements BeanFactoryAware, FactoryBean<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy getObject() throws Exception {
        final CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy sas = beanFactory.getBean(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.class);
        return sas;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SessionAuthenticationStrategy.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

... and make it available on you XML configuration:

```
<bean id="sas" class="com.example.SessionAuthenticationStrategyFactoryBean" />

<bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    class=" o.s.scurity.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">

   <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas">
   ...
</bean>
```