# SAML authenticated users don't appear in Spring Security's SessionRegistry

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, spring-saml

Our application used to have only one possibility to log in: username and password. Once a new user logged into the application, their session would appear in Spring Security's `SessionRegistry`.

Now I'm implementing SAML support with the help of Spring SAML. I oriented the setup heavily towards the [sample application's configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml). It all works fine. However I noticed that users that log in via SAML don't get their session added to the `SessionRegistry`.

The usual context file for form based authentication contains the following:

```
<session-management 
  invalid-session-url="/login"
  session-fixation-protection="newSession"
  session-authentication-error-url="/login?invalid_session=1">

  <concurrency-control
    max-sessions="1"
    error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"
    session-registry-alias="springSessionRegistry"/>

</session-management>
```

In my `http` element for the SAML configuration I added the same. This created a new `SessionRegistry` but it did not contain anything. I also tried

```
<concurrency-control session-registry-ref="springSessionRegistry"/>
```

but this did not contain any SAML authenticated sessions either.

So how can I access SAML sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that bean definition parsers of Spring Security only automatically link beans created based on the `session-management` and `concurrency-control` to the authentication processors included in core Spring Security modules. This means, that `SAMLProcessingFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy()` isn't called.

You should be able to get it working by declaring the `samlWebSSOProcessingFilter` bean in the following way (which refers to the concurrency bean automatically created by the `concurrency-control` element):

```
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy#0"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I had to use `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#2` because I have multiple `http` elements. I'm sure this is a very brittle setup; I think I have to create my own session control strategy manually to make it reliable as it is [impossible to refer to the strategy in a reliable way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26429967/188107). Thanks for your great library and for the support you provide!

Comment: Glad it helped. I agree that this is far from ideal and creating own strategy is definitely a better option. In a long run I'll try to get call to this class included directly in the bean def. parsers.

Comment: Thanks @VladimírSchäfer

Comment: @VladimírSchäfer do you have any example of Java configuration for the samlWebSSSOProcessing filter? We have the same issue: with the samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy), the users are not added in the SessionRegistry.

Comment: At the end, I understood that my problem was that I was only adding a ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy to samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy, and I needed a CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy, with the ConcurrentSessionStrat AND a RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy, otherwise the new logged users were not registered in the SessionRegistry of Spring Security.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment of Vladimir's answer, my problem was that I was adding only a ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy to the samlWebSSOProcessingFilter, and because of that, the new logged users were not registered in the SessionRegistry of Spring Security.

To fix that, I created a CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy like this:

```java
   @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());

        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(authStrategy());
        
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return the strategy for the SAML authentication: ConcurrentSessionControl (max 1 session per user)
     *      + RegisterSessionAuthStrat (otherwise, the session of the users are not tracked when they authenticate with SAML)
     *
     * @author Cyril Gambis
     * @date 27 juil. 2020
     */
    private CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy authStrategy() {
        List<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> strategies = new ArrayList<>();
        
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentStrategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(this.sessionRegistry);
        concurrentStrategy.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(false);

        RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerStrategy = new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(this.sessionRegistry);
        
        strategies.add(concurrentStrategy);
        strategies.add(registerStrategy);
        
        CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeStrategy = new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(strategies);
        
        return compositeStrategy;
    }
```

Now, the new users are correctly registered.